# Java MongoClient connected successful or not

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java

I am using the "New and Better" way to create MongoClient like the following

```
String MONGO_URI = "mongodb://username:password@127.0.0.1:27017";
MongoClientURI mongoClientURI = new MongoClientURI(MONGODB_URI);
mongoClient = new MongoClient(mongoClientURI);
```

The question is: how to check if the mongoClient is successfully created or not?

The **MongoClient** constructor could fail, caused by anything not correct in the string (address is wrong, credential is not correct, etc.). Want to catch the error immediately when it happens.

There is no exception to catch and do not see any function in mongoClient to check it.

Tried the following

```
try {
    mongoClient = new MongoClient(mongoClientURI);
    MongoDatabase admin_db = mongoClient.getDatabase(WELL-KNOWN-DB-NAME);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Nothing was caught for the two function calls.

The connection setup **failed**, confirmed by the Exception info printed on console by Mongodb library:

```
INFO: Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server 127.0.0.1:27017
com.mongodb.MongoSecurityException: Exception authenticating MongoCredential{mechanism=null, userName='admin', source='admin', password=<hidden>, mechanismProperties={}}
    at com.mongodb.connection.SaslAuthenticator.authenticate(SaslAuthenticator.java:61)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultAuthenticator.authenticate(DefaultAuthenticator.java:32)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.authenticateAll(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:99)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:44)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:115)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:127)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 18: 'Authentication failed.' on server 127.0.0.1:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "Authentication failed.", "code" : 18, "codeName" : "AuthenticationFailed" }
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.createCommandFailureException(CommandHelper.java:170)
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.receiveCommandResult(CommandHelper.java:123)
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:32)
    at com.mongodb.connection.SaslAuthenticator.sendSaslContinue(SaslAuthenticator.java:99)
    at com.mongodb.connection.SaslAuthenticator.authenticate(SaslAuthenticator.java:58)
    ... 6 more
```

Answer (score 0):

This: `new MongoClient()` will throw an exception if it is unable to communicate with the server.

For example:

```
com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 1 ms while waiting for a server
```

More generally; it will throw a subclass of `MongoClientException` which is a subclass of `RuntimeException` and hence is not declared to be thrown by the `MongoClient` constructor. So, if you want to catch **any** exception thrown when you create a `MongoClient` ...

```
try {
    String MONGO_URI = "mongodb://username:password@127.0.0.1:27017";
    MongoClientURI mongoClientURI = new MongoClientURI(MONGODB_URI);
    mongoClient = new MongoClient(mongoClientURI);
} catch (Exception ex) {
    // ... do something
}
```

In addition, any subsequent attempt to use a `MongoClient` instance will fail if its underlying server is no longer available. If you want to implement a periodic healthcheck to verify that the underlying server remains available then 'getting' a well known database might be a simple, reliable means of testing success / provoking a failure. For example:

```
MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("TheNameOfADatabaseToBeUsedForHealthChecking");
// you have to force the execution of a server side action to prove that the undelrying server is available
db.getCollection("TheNameOfASmallCollection").count();
```

Comment: I tried to surround the constructor and mongoClient.getDatabase("wellKnowDBName"), but could not catch any exception.

Comment: That suggests that the underlying server is up and running and hence the `MongoClient` can talk to it. BTW, the string "wellKnownDatabasename" is not a constant, it's just a suggestion, a placeholder for a database on your system which you can rely on always being present.

Comment: Your question talks about how to deterine whether the underlying server is available. So, if you wrap `new MongoClient(...)` in a try/catch (like I showed in my answer) then you can be sure that the client is valid and useable as soon as it is created. For additional safety you might choose to run a periodic heartbeat to check that the server remains available, if so then running a benign command such as `getDatabase` (assuming you supply a database name which you _know_ exists) would suffice.

Comment: I gave the wrong password for the connection, so there is no way of the connection is set up. It is confirmed by the console print out of the MongoException. Looks Mongo Code catches the exception and does not throw it out.

Comment: I don't think the client is swallowing an exception, I think it is just lazily evaulating / postponing the server side call for as long as possible. I have updated the question to show a call which **will** fail if the underlying server is not available. Bear in mind, that this only relates to the 'periodic healthcheck' suggesion. I suspect that the other suggestion (to wrap `new MongoClient(...)` in a try/catch) is your must have and periodic healthchecking is a nice to have.